# Xaml selected item color binding of canvas within a listview

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

In WinRT and xaml, I have managed to get my ListView to look like this...

[image]

The problem is that the cloud on the second item should be the white foreground.

How this list is currently built up is with a Style of TargetType="ListViewItem" where I set the ListViewItemPresenter SelectedForeground="White". This sorts out the textblocks as per the image above.

The 'sun/cloud' is on a databound converter that has a style as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="CloudWeather"
       TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Viewbox Width="50"
                         Height="50">
                    <Canvas x:Name="cloudy"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Height="58.180798"
                            UseLayoutRounding="False"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Width="80">
                        <Path Data="F1M29.09,58.18C13.023,58.18 0,45.156 0,29.09 0,13.024 13.023,0 29.09,0 40.008,0 49.508,6.024 54.484,14.918 55.691,14.711 56.918,14.543 58.184,14.543 70.234,14.543 80,24.313 80,36.363 80,48.41 70.234,58.18 58.184,58.18z M58.184,50.906C66.219,50.906 72.73,44.395 72.73,36.363 72.73,28.332 66.219,21.817 58.184,21.817 55.273,21.817 52.578,22.692 50.301,24.164 48.063,14.5 39.441,7.274 29.09,7.274 17.043,7.274 7.273,17.039 7.273,29.09 7.273,41.141 17.043,50.906 29.09,50.906 35.668,50.906 52.691,50.906 58.184,50.906z"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              Height="58.18"
                              Canvas.Left="0"
                              Stretch="None"
                              Canvas.Top="-0.181"
                              Width="80" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notice the **Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"**

The problem is that it picks up the Foreground of the ListView, but not the **SelectedForeground**. How can I get the path fill to use the selected foreground color? This is WinRT (Store Apps), so I don't think that I can use triggers or more complex binding (AncestorType)

Comment: Did you try talking to your `TemplatedParent` via `RelativeSource` so instead like `{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`?

Comment: @Chris for the idea. It runs, but the behaviour is the same. I think that the Foreground property of the ListView is still the the same (white) and the canvas is oblivious to SelectedForeground

Comment: Ya, but somewhere in that item style template there's a `ColorAnimation` changing the foreground property of the ContentPresenter, your ContentControl you're plopping in there is not receiving that animation since apparently it's not getting hit with that TargetProperty to SolidColorBrush.Color, so we need to figure out how to get hit by that animation as well, like if you pulled that Path out of your ContentControl and put it directly into the item template, it would inherit that property change to Foreground, almost guaranteed. Make sense?

Comment: In other words, pull out your path, leave the same templatebinding, put it in an itemstemplate for your ListBox or whatever, and it will change from the ColorAnimation set in the "Selected" state for that item....just as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I found a post by Mike Taulty [Windows 8.1: ListViews, GridViews, ListViewItemPresenter, GridViewItemPresenter](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/12/07/windows-8-1-listviews-gridviews-listviewitempresenter-gridviewitempresenter.aspx). He experienced a similar problem and observed that WinRT doesn't have RelativeSource binding with the Mode=Ancestor.

The solution is to bind to a ViewModel brush (I have the ViewModel anyway) and set **two-way** binding from the ListViewItemPresenter **Foreground** to the ViewModel. That way, when the foreground changes, it updates the ViewModel which, in turn, is bound to the path fill.

It is a less elegant workaround, but does solve my problem. Here's what it looks like now... finally.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have managed this using a **PathIcon** instead of a **Path**.

The PathIcon has a Foreground property that the **ListViewItemsPresenter** will dynamically change for you when you select/deselect an item.

eg.

```
<PathIcon Data="F1M29.09,58.18C13.023,58.18 0,45.156 0,29.09 0,13.024 13.023,0 29.09,0 40.008,0 49.508,6.024 54.484,14.918 55.691,14.711 56.918,14.543 58.184,14.543 70.234,14.543 80,24.313 80,36.363 80,48.41 70.234,58.18 58.184,58.18z M58.184,50.906C66.219,50.906 72.73,44.395 72.73,36.363 72.73,28.332 66.219,21.817 58.184,21.817 55.273,21.817 52.578,22.692 50.301,24.164 48.063,14.5 39.441,7.274 29.09,7.274 17.043,7.274 7.273,17.039 7.273,29.09 7.273,41.141 17.043,50.906 29.09,50.906 35.668,50.906 52.691,50.906 58.184,50.906z"
          Height="58.18"
          Canvas.Left="0"
          Stretch="None"
          Canvas.Top="-0.181"
          Width="80" />
```